# "Compile with" option missing in the Eclipse while creating Android Appllication project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am facing a weird problem with eclipse.
As the title says, while doing Eclipse->new->android application project , i get screen with all options, but "compile with" place is emptpy. 
[image]

I tried in the preference for the sdk and it shows as below image.
[image]

please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your ADT plugun version.
Try it again by updating your ADT version.

Comment: Goto Window-->Android sdk manager and install all tools and plugins.After that create a default android emulator by going to Window-->Android vitual device manager.Hope that works.